# Missing letters iOS App label with custom font

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, fonts

I have an iOS App which contains custom fonts. Everything works properly, but once in a while the labels with the custom fonts will randomly have missing letters.
Any ideas?

**This is a pic of the app working properly**
[image: Working properly]

**This is the app showing missing letters**
[image: Not working]

Comment: This sounds like a bug. You might want to try to make a minimal app to reproduce the problem and if you can reproduce it with said minimal app, file a bug report with Apple (attaching the demo project, of course). As for how to work around this meanwhile: you might want to try drawing the text yourself, first simply with `[string drawInRect:rect attributes:attributes];` and if that still triggers the bug (would be interesting for the bug report), try CoreText. A bit more work, but might be worth a try.

Comment: The labels frames look funny, are you sure they are sized & positioned correctly ?

Comment: @A-Live: Don't know why you think they look funny, but you're right: give the labels a background color so you can see whether it's a layouting/size issue.

Comment: @DarkDust It is not a layouting issue, the label is there, in fact some letters appear, but other do not.